# Xamarin Forms: CarouselPage moves vertically when NavigationBar is off

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having the same issue as this post, does anyone have a simple fix for this?

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/105415/carouselpage-moves-vertically-when-navigationbar-is-off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this by using this CarouselViewControl, it's very simple to use and the tutorial is very straight forward

https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView